# How to create a date of birth column in R

Tags: r

I have made the following tibble:

```
mytibble <- tibble::tibble(
  name = c("Max", "Andrew", "Emanuel", "Ellie", "Maggie"),
  birth_year = c(2000, 2004, 2002, 2001, 1999),
  birth_month = c(3, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  birth_day = c(13, 17, 28, 21, 4))
```

And I want to create a column that shows the date of birth eg 2000/3/13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
mytibble %>% 
mutate(dateofbirth = paste(birth_year, birth_month, birth_day, sep = '/'))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  name    birth_year birth_month birth_day dateofbirth
  <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      
1 Max           2000           3        13 2000/3/13  
2 Andrew        2004           3        17 2004/3/17  
3 Emanuel       2002           4        28 2002/4/28  
4 Ellie         2001           5        21 2001/5/21  
5 Maggie        1999           6         4 1999/6/4
```

If you want the new column in Date format, you can do:

```
mytibble %>% 
mutate(dateofbirth = paste(birth_year, birth_month, birth_day, sep = '/')) %>% 
mutate(dateofbirth = lubridate::ymd(dateofbirth))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  name    birth_year birth_month birth_day dateofbirth
  <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     
1 Max           2000           3        13 2000-03-13 
2 Andrew        2004           3        17 2004-03-17 
3 Emanuel       2002           4        28 2002-04-28 
4 Ellie         2001           5        21 2001-05-21 
5 Maggie        1999           6         4 1999-06-04
```

Comment: I assume, you'd calculate from today the age, if so, see if this works: mytibble %>% mutate(dateofbirth = paste(birth_year, birth_month, birth_day, sep = '/')) %>% 
  mutate(dateofbirth = lubridate::ymd(dateofbirth)) %>% mutate(age = as.numeric((Sys.Date() - dateofbirth)/365)) It'll give you age in years approx

Comment: I get the following error:

Problem with `mutate()` input `dateofbirth`.
ℹ  1 failed to parse.
ℹ Input `dateofbirth` is `lubridate::ymd(dateofbirth)`. 1 failed to parse.

Comment: So we are using three columns to create date column first, are there any values in any of them that don't add up? For example in month column do you have values greater than 12 for ex.

Comment: It's telling us exactly that it failed to parse 1 date. can you check you data using head and tail? Preferably after creation of first dateofbirth column using paste function, this way you only need to look at one column.